# Replace Images in Word Document with string/text placeholder

Tags: image, vba, ms-word

I have a 2010 Word document with some images. I have already exported out the images one by one. Because of the formatting of the document's destination, I need to remove all the images and leave a text block (something like [[Image1.jpg]]) where the image once was.

The name of the image is actually unimportant. I just need to swap the image for text. I am completely new to VBA in Word.

Here is some other code to resize the images, can this be modified to delete the image and at that location, insert some text?

```
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oILShp As InlineShape

For Each oShp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    With oShp
        .Height = AspectHt(.Width, .Height, _
        CentimetersToPoints(11))
        .Width = CentimetersToPoints(11)
    End With
Next

For Each oILShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With oILShp
        .Height = AspectHt(.Width, .Height, _
        CentimetersToPoints(11))
        .Width = CentimetersToPoints(11)
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the problem is that you want to replace `Shapes`, too, but shapes could be located anywhere within document text- above, in-between, side-to, etc. Where do you want to place your text in such situations?

Comment: i think the good news is there are no shapes, if we're talking about images outside the margins. all the images are within the margins and are using Text Warp, so no existing text should interfere with the actual image.

Comment: so, let's assume there are only `InlineShapes`. some more questions- do you want to add text block with information [image.jpg] or you want to count and increase number of each it it like [image1.jpg], [image2.jpg], etc?

Comment: The increment is not necessary since I am acquiring the document's images by saving as an HTML file, this creates a subfolder with the images. But if the image was altered (color, resized, etc) it saves another image. So the doc could have 3 embedded images, but the HTML subfolder has 6 because i resized them all in Word. the images are for uploading to a Wiki, so the placeholder will be a nice for identifying image locations only, not the literal image file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible solutions  which will work with `InlineShapes` only (according to comments that could be ok.)

**Solution 1** constant replacement text:

```
Sub ReplaceInlineShapes_constant_names()

Dim oILShp As InlineShape

For Each oILShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

    'insert text in place where InlineShape is located
    ActiveDocument.Range(oILShp.Range.Start, oILShp.Range.End).Text = "[Image.Jpg]"
    'delete picture is not needed- it was simply replaced with text

Next
End Sub
```

**Solution 2** replacement text with index within:

```
Sub ReplaceInlineShapes_WithIndex()

Dim oILShp As InlineShape
Dim ILShpIndex As Integer
For Each oILShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    ILShpIndex = ILShpIndex + 1
    'insert text in place where InlineShape is located
    ActiveDocument.Range(oILShp.Range.Start, oILShp.Range.End).Text = _
                                "[Image" & ILShpIndex & ".Jpg]"
    'delete picture is not needed- it was simply replaced with text

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, i like option 2 for sake of counting the expected number of images.